# Is $M\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ convex?

Tags: complex-numbers, convex-analysis

Let us consider the following set of $ \mathbb{C}^2$:
$$
M=\{(a\overline{c}+2,-a\overline{c}-4\overline{b}+1);\;(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{C}^3\;\;\hbox{and}\;|c|=1\}
$$

> Is $M\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$  convex?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: It seems like $M$ is same as $\Bbb{C}^2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $c=1$ and $(z_1,z_2)$ be a give point in $\Bbb{C}^2.$ Then choosing $a,b$ accordingly we have $M=\Bbb{C}^2.$

Comment: @Student You should accept this answer. Bumblebee was the first to notice that $M=\Bbb{C}^2$!

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Actually $M=\mathbb{C}^2$ and therefore it is a convex set.
Let $(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ then
$$(z,w)=(a\overline{c}+2,-a\overline{c}-4\overline{b}+1)$$
with $c=1$, $a=z-2$, $b=\frac{3-\overline{z}-\overline{w}}{4}$. Hence $M=\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: Just 48 seconds…