# Question of convexity in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, convex-analysis

Let us consider the following set of $ \mathbb{C}^2$:
$$
S=\{(b\overline{a},b\overline{c});\;(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{C}^3\;\;\hbox{and}\;|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2=1\}
$$

> I want to prove that $S$ is not a convex set of $\mathbb{C}^2$, but perhaps it is convex.

Thank you

Comment: $(1; \frac{5}{2})\in S$. Take $b=1$ and $a=1/2$. $S$ is convex. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548627/is-m-subseteq-mathbbc2-convex?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Why is the midpoint not in S? Take a=0.5+i0 and b=1+i0

Comment: oui must have and ineaqulity in that definition of the set S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\zeta$ be any unit vector in $\mathbb C$. Then the set $S$ contains $r\sqrt{1-r^2}e^{i\theta}\zeta$ for every $r\in [0,1]$ and all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, we can write $r\zeta = (\bar a, \bar c)$ and get $|b| = \sqrt{1-|a|^2-|c|^2} = \sqrt{1-r^2}$. So, 
$$
S = \{r\sqrt{1-r^2}e^{i\theta}\zeta : 0\le r\le 1, \theta \in\mathbb{R}, \zeta \text{ a unit vector in } \mathbb{C}^2\}
$$
Since $r\sqrt{1-r^2}$ takes on all values in $[0,1/2]$ as $r$ runs through $[0, 1]$, the description of $S$ simplifies further to 
$$
S = \{w\zeta : w\in \mathbb{C}, |w|\le 1/2, \zeta \text{ a unit vector in } \mathbb{C}^2\}
$$
But this is precisely the set of all vectors $\xi\in \mathbb{C}^2$ such that $|\xi|\le 1/2$, namely the closed ball  of radius $1/2$. It is convex.